# JavaFx WebView video: onended event

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

I'm making a JavaFX app that uses `Webview` to display a local HTML page. Upon loading the page into the `Webview`, an initial video is displayed by calling the JavaScript function `open()`. The function attaches a `onended` event listener to the `<video>` element.  Unfortunately, I cannot get the `onended` event to fire, although the `playing` event does.

Javascript:

```
function open()
{
    //set position
    pos = 0;
    //display the black, add video, play.
    var video = document.getElementById('vid');
    video.style.display = "block";
    video.setAttribute('src', breakout);
    video.load();
    video.play();

    //video.addEventListener("playing", clear, false);
    video.addEventListener("ended", clear, false); 
}

function clear()
{
    alert("clear"); //was the method called? 
    //clear anything that was displayed.
    document.getElementById('vid').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('vid').setAttribute('src', "");
    document.getElementById('image').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', "");
    //get next.
    change();
}
```

Java:

```
public class WebviewController
{

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;
    private WebEngine engine;
    private State state;

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WebEvent<String> event)
            {
                Dialog<Void> alert = new Dialog<>();
                alert.getDialogPane().setContentText(event.getData());
                alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        engine.load(getClass().getResource("/web/newhtml.html").t‌​oExternalForm());
        afterLoad();
    }

    public void afterLoad()
    {
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<Worker.State>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState)
            {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
                {
                    breakout();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void breakout()
    {
        engine.executeScript("open()");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-8">
     <div class="slideshow">
            <video id="vid" src=""></video>
            <img id="image" src='' alt="" />
      </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `onended="clear()"` to the video Element to see if it was a problem with the JavaScript `Open()` method, this didn't work. I also tried firing a `playing` event (as commented), which worked.  So it appears to be a problem with the `onended` event trigger.

What am I missing to get the `onended` event to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you've got a bug with WebView. Actually, it's a little primitive utility. For example, I'm not able to play [Big Back Bunny](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4) video but I've run a simple test with another video on JDK 1.8.0_121 and it works:

```
public class VideoTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener((webView, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> {
            System.out.println(message + "[at " + lineNumber + "]");
        });

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        StringBuilder codeBuilder = new StringBuilder("<video id='test' src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' width='200' height='200' controls></video>");
        codeBuilder.append("<script>");
        codeBuilder.append("document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('playing', function(e) { console.log('playing'); }, false);");
        codeBuilder.append("document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('ended', function(e) { console.log('ended'); }, false);");
        codeBuilder.append("document.querySelector('#test').load();");
        codeBuilder.append("document.querySelector('#test').play();");
        codeBuilder.append("</script>");
        engine.loadContent(codeBuilder.toString());

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

[image: App preview]

Anyway, I have a few suggestions on how to work with WebView:

- Instead of `alert()`, you can print to console by `WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener` from `com.sun.javafx.webkit` package
- Try to be precise, you should register listeners first, then you can call functions like `load()` or `play()`
- Make your code as simple as you possibly can and extend it piece by piece

You can also try to replace WebView with [MediaView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) or by using other embedded browser component. For instance, you can use [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef) (*Java Chromium Embedded Framework*)